# Unable to append the string using jQuery after specific text

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, insertafter

I have an URL:

```
https://papermusepress.scene7.com/is/image/papermusepress?layer=0&src=fxg{papermusepress/5x7Shape3?$Embed1_5x7Shape3=BBS_BM0V_011_00&**imageres=300**}&scl=1&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=90&extend=10,10,10,10&effect=-1&blendMode=mult&op_grow=3&op_blur=4&color=0,0,0,120
```

and I need to insert a `&wid=800&hei=800` after `imageres=300`, so the resulting URL would be:

```
https://papermusepress.scene7.com/is/image/papermusepress?layer=0&src=fxg{papermusepress/5x7Shape3?$Embed1_5x7Shape3=BBS_BM0V_011_00&imageres=300&wid=800&hei=800}&scl=1&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=90&extend=10,10,10,10&effect=-1&blendMode=mult&op_grow=3&op_blur=4&color=0,0,0,120
```

What would be the simplest way to do this in jQuery? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: `url = url.replace('imageres=300}', 'imageres=300&wid=800&hei=800}')` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var url1 = 'https://papermusepress.scene7.com/is/image/papermusepress?layer=0&src=fxg{papermusepress/5x7Shape3?$Embed1_5x7Shape3=BBS_BM0V_011_00&imageres=300}&scl=1&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=90&extend=10,10,10,10&effect=-1&blendMode=mult&op_grow=3&op_blur=4&color=0,0,0,120';
var url = url1.split('?');
params = url[2];
params =  params.split('&');
params = params[1].split('}');
var old_image = params[0];
var new_image = old_image.concat('&wid=800&hei=800');
url2 = url1.replace(old_image, new_image);
alert(url2);

please use above java script and run. don't worry about variables.

it run fine for me
```

Comment: hi sameer.. 'imageres=300' value 300 can be variable.. it will vary image to image can u suggest any generic code..!!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you can append only 256 characters in your url. more than that will result in error or the request will be denined.

Comment: its scen7 urls of images